# Indent proof environment

Tags: indentation, proof-package

This is standard proof environmet.
[image: normal proof environment]

But I want to indent the body of proof like this. How should I code?

[image]

This is my header.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,cleveref,enumitem,thmtools}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace,mathtools}
```

Comment: there is no "standard" proof environment, but many packages define one, you have tagged this proof-package are you using a package of that name? (I do not have that) or amsthm, or theorem or ntheorem or ....

Comment: Please tell us how the `proof` environment is defined or, alternatively, how you generated the upper screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine the `proof` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \list{}{%
    \settowidth{\leftmargin}{\itshape\proofname:\hskip\labelsep}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
  }%
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape#1\@addpunct{:}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{proof}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, don't underline! Please! And don't indent either.